# sendmail setup and config

Tags: email, sendmail

I am trying to figure out how to setup sendmail to allow for mail to be sent between two machines. In my case here's what I did.

- Installed sendmail
- commented the line where sendmail was servicing only localhost
- added both machines to eachother's hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 debian
192.168.x.x kilo
```

and the same for `kilo` just with the address for `debian` host.
What do I need to configure next to allow for these two hosts to exchange email. I have tried everything I have seen online but couldn't get anything to work.
If I try to send any email I get this error.

```
  The following addresses had permanent fatal errors <romeo@debian> [reason: 550 Host unknown] 
  Transcript of session follows   550 5.1.2 <romeo@debian>... Host unknown [Name server: debian: host not found]
```

I know it might be seem like I am missing something really important but I can't for the life of me wrap my head around the configuration. Would really appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your /etc/hosts file is not parsed.

in sendmail.mc:

```
define(`confHOSTS_FILE', `/etc/hosts')dnl
```

rebuilding this should result in sendmail.cf

```
O HostsFile=/etc/hosts
```

After restart the hostnames should be valid.

Check DNS has no entry:

```
$ host debian
Host debian not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Test with

```
sendmail -bv user@debian
```

expected output:

```
$ sendmail -bv user@debian
deliverable: mailer esmtp, host debian, user user@debian
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sendmail: sending email to hosts on the same private IP network without DNS records

Sendmail "does not like" host names without doamin part.
For sendmail use names  with domain part in your `/etc/hosts` e.g.

```
192.168.0.2 kilo.example.net kilo
```

P.S. There are internet sites offering free DNS (sub)domains.